does this feature from dating app Hinge infringe this patent from dating app Bumble?
Bumble's patent:
US20210400001A1
https://patents.google.com/patent/US20210400001A1/en?oq=US20210400001A1
Hinge's feature:
https://hingeapp.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/29975672282899-What-is-Are-You-Sure
Based on their description, it seems identical in every way.

If you are going to ask about infringement, at least link to the actual patent and not the application. Claims can narrow considerably. https://patents.google.com/patent/US12028297B2/en?oq=US20210400001A1

why would the actual patent and the application be different? Is the application the provisional?

Claims in patents are very often narrower than those found in the corresponding application.

how can I tell if a google document is an application or an actual patent?

Applications start with the year of filing like: US2021... and end with a A1 (usually). Patents are sequentially numbered with newish ones in the 11 to 12 millions. Also US patent numbers end with B1 or B2. Many applications never get granted so always look for the actual patent.

It may be "infringing" but there is lots of room to argue that the claims of the patent are invalid.
For one thing, Claim 1 recites "comparing the proposed communication to a set of effective communication policies" which is extremely broad (including, e.g., advanced AI solutions) but the specification only describes the much narrower criterion of searching for specific known spam phrases. This causes LizardTech problems for Claim 1, especially since dependent claims already recite the narrower criterion just like in LizardTech.
There is also room to argue abstract idea (for all of the Claims).

What about the claims of this continued applications: https://patents.google.com/patent/US12028297B2/en?oq=US20210400001A1

US20210400001A1

In that application Claim 1 recites "determining that the first electronic communication is unlikely to solicit a reply" while the specification says nothing about the underlying methodology used to assess the likelihood of replies. It does say more that the other patent about effective communication policies though. But even those added statements are more along the lines of a direction for further research than a reduction to practice, even if one is willing to make the conceptual leap to bridge "effective communication" with "likelihood of replies".

Based on the level of detail provided I might agree but note that the issued claim 1 is narrower than the claim 1 of the application.
